What exactly is the area used in the equation R=ρl/A to find the resistance of an electrolyte?
My textbook says the resistance $R$ of a water column filled with some electrolyte is
$$R=ρl/A,$$
where $ρ$ is the resistivity, $l$ is the distance between the electrodes, and $A$ is the area of cross section of the water column.
If this is true, then I think immersing electrodes in the sea with a huge area of cross section should offer zero resistance, which is not the case (I do not mean just seawater, I mean dipping the electrodes in a large water body filled with ions). What is this area, exactly?

The formula above is applicable only at some specific conditions:

The conducting medium is homogenous.
The cross-section area A of a conductive medium must be constant along all the distance between the electrodes.
The electrodes must cover the whole cross-section area.
Conditionally, if surrounding has considerable conductivity too, electrode sizes must be much bigger than distance, so there can be approximately assumed the electrostatic field is homogenous, I.e. the field gradient vectors are parallel and constant.

Otherwise it is rather complicated calculation involving integration, local resistivity and vectors of the field gradient and the  current density.
$$\vec E = \rho \cdot \vec J,$$
which is the vector, local form of the more known, scalar, integral form of the Ohm law $U = R\cdot I$.
$$\mathrm{d}U=\vec E \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec l$$
$$\mathrm{d}I=\vec J \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec A$$
You can already imply the sea case is out of applicability of the simple geometrical formula $$R=\rho \cdot \frac lA$$

Note that resistivity is generally a tensor, as taking it as a scalar is applicable only on an isotropic medium. The consequence is, if there are local variations in resistivity, vectors of the electrostatic field gradient and current density are not generally parallel.
